# Use of previous not null state of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to carry forward the previous state of data wherever data is not available.

For example, I have this data:

```
Month   Order   Amount
----------------------
   1    Item1   100
   1    Item2   200
   1    Item3   300
   2    NULL    NULL
   3    Item4   100
   4    NULL    NULL
   5    NULL    NULL
   6    Item1   100
```

So in the above example I want to use 1st month's information to be carry forwarded as it is for 2nd month. Also since 3rd month's information is available then use it for the month 4 and 5.

Hence the output will be the following:

```
Month   Order   Amount
----------------------
   1    Item1   100
   1    Item2   200
   1    Item3   300
   2    Item1   100
   2    Item2   200
   2    Item3   300
   3    Item4   100
   4    Item4   100
   5    Item4   100
   6    Item1   100
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @Larnu: because there are no rows for those items in the original dataset. Month 3 consists only of "Item4 / 100", so month 4 and 5 do likewise. Essentially the data is divvied up into equivalence classes, with the `NULL` months classed the same as the most recent non-`NULL` month and having the same rows. Peculiar logic indeed, but queryable (though I'm not motivated to produce the query).

Comment: it seems you want a LAG function. but it is not clear the order in which you will evaluate your data set.

Comment: @Randy Not sure how to do this with LAG. Any Month needs either it's own value or if it has null values, every row from the previous non-NULL Month. The mapping could be to any number of rows for the most recent non-NULL Month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a `LEFT JOIN`. If you join on "Month", you can ensure that the joined "Month" has the higest value (so far) and also has a non-NULL "Order".

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM      myTable t1
  LEFT JOIN myTable t2 ON t2.Month = (SELECT MAX(Month)
                                        FROM myTable
                                       WHERE Month <= t1.Month
                                         AND [Order] IS NOT NULL)
```

You'll get too many rows at first, since "Month" 1 will give 9 rows. You can remove those by also ensuring that the joined "Month" is strictly lower:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM      myTable t1
  LEFT JOIN myTable t2 ON t2.Month = (SELECT MAX(Month)
                                        FROM myTable
                                       WHERE Month <= t1.Month
                                         AND [Order] IS NOT NULL)
                      AND t1.Month > t2.Month
```

Then you only need to `SELECT` the right columns:

```sql
SELECT t1.Month,
       COALESCE(t1.[Order],t2.[Order]) as [Order],
       COALESCE(t1.Amount,t2.Amount) as Amount
  FROM      myTable t1
  LEFT JOIN myTable t2 ON t2.Month = (SELECT MAX(Month)
                                        FROM myTable
                                       WHERE Month <= t1.Month
                                         AND [Order] IS NOT NULL)
                      AND t1.Month > t2.Month
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=20b4749e9f71948dd4668ff4ac842afa)

Comment: Thanks a lot this works perfectly :). I will try to optimise the same further!